Android Studio segfaults on launch (Manjaro linux x86_64)
I have tried to install android studio via snap, via pamac build with AUR repos on, and with raw standalone .tar.gz archive from official website (https://developer.android.com/studio).
My setup is:

Manjaro Linux 24.0.8,
16G RAM + 32G swap,
x86_64 AMD Ryzen 5 5600H (with Radeon Graphics)
NVidia GeForce RTX 3050 Laptop

In all cases I got exactly the same result - android studio, when launched, instantly reports SIGSEGV and exits with code 134:
$ android-studio
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x0000000000000000, pid=105122, tid=105138
#
# JRE version:  (17.0.11) (build )
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (17.0.11+0-17.0.11b1207.24-11852314, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libjimage.so+0xbfe5]  ZipDecompressor::decompress_resource(unsigned char*, unsigned char*, ResourceHeader*, ImageStrings const*)+0x25
#
...
[error occurred during error reporting (), id 0x6, SIGABRT (0x6) at pc=0x000074bc60ad83f4]

zsh: IOT instruction (core dumped)  android-studio
$ echo $?
134

I stripped some info. Full console output is available here: https://pastebin.com/cQgeFpzG .
Full error log is available here: https://pastebin.com/GTdfrky3 .
I think, that [libjimage.so+0xbfe5]  ZipDecompressor::decompress_resource being marked as "problematic code" might be a hint, but i failed to find any related info. Moreover, i failed to find anything about related to android studio segfaulting.
Expected result: I type android-studio in my terminal, android studio launches and opens a window.
